# Method to convert simultaneous key chord / letter key combo into another key?

Tags: x11, key-mapping, xmonad

I'm looking for a method to make simultaneous key presses trigger another, e.g. for the keys <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, pressed simultaneously, to trigger another key press, say, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

My ultimate goal (in case it makes a difference) is to make a `vim`-like XMonad configuration: that is, I would like to use the simultaneous key chord <kbd>W</kbd>/ <kbd>E</kbd>/<kbd>F</kbd> to "escape" into "Normal Mode" (a XMonad.Actions.Submap (submap)).

So far, I have tried `xbindkeys` but have not figured out how to specify a key chord of that sort.

Comment: Part of the problem is that there is no such thing to an X server or client as "simultaneous key presses," except for modifier keys such as Ctrl and Alt. Whatever code would be involved would have to look for XKeyPress events for W, E, and F in **any** order **sequentially.**

Comment: Just a method for checking in any particular order (say, W->E->F) should be fine, since I could just implement the check for all 6 possible orderings (or maybe refactor it to check them all).

Comment: @spacingissue, I'm really interested in this topic. So far, the only way to achieve this result is to use Karabiner on OS X and running Linux on a VM. I would love to have chords on native Linux. Please, whenever you have updates, add comment to this question!

Comment: You will probably have to write your own program, because you need to delay the keypress events until you receive the release events, or it's clear the keys currently pressed cannot be extended to any configured combination. Note that this will break any program that depends on both press/release events and the time between them.